# displaying in a label the number of times an item is randomly selected

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My label2 is supposed to display how many times each item(here the apple) appears
That is to say if apple is selected my counter(label2) should display 1 then 2, three..
But it doesnt seem to work.

```
from tkinter import*
import random, time

wn=Tk()
wn.geometry("300x300")
mytext=Text(wn,bg="pink",width=10,height=200)
mytext.pack()
label1=Label(wn,text="",bg="yellow",bd=3)
label1.place(x=200,y=20)
label2=Label(wn,text="",bg="lightgreen",bd=3)
label2.place(x=200,y=50)
def update(c=0):
    numx = 0
    list1=["apple","orange","melon","carrot"]
    fruit = random.choice(list1)
    label1["text"]=fruit
    if label1["text"]=="apple":
        numx+=1
        label2["text"]=numx
    mytext.insert('end', str(fruit) + '\n')
    wn.after(1000, update, c+1)
update()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `numx` to be zero everytime `update` is called.

First move `numx` outside your `update` function, and then declare `global` inside `update`:

```
from tkinter import*
import random, time

wn=Tk()

...

numx = 0

def update(c=0):
    global numx
    ...

update()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

As @HenryYik pointed out, you code requires to first declare `numx = 0` in the global space, then declare it global inside your `update` function.

An alternate approach to solving your problem is to use a `collections.Counter`; it has the advantage to simplify the code logic in `update`, and, in case you needed it, it also keeps a tally of the number of times each fruit was selected.
The list of fruits is also declared outside the function `update`, making the code more general.

Something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from collections import Counter


def update(delay=1000):
    """picks a fruit at random, and updates the display and the tally
    calls itself again after a time delay
    """    
    fruit = random.choice(fruit_list)
    counter[fruit] += 1

    label1['text'] = fruit
    label2['text'] = counter['apple']
    mytext.insert('end', str(fruit) + '\n')

    wn.after(delay, update)


fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'carrot']    
counter = Counter()

wn = tk.Tk()
wn.geometry('300x300')

mytext = tk.Text(wn, bg='pink', width=10, height=200)
mytext.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(wn, text='', bg='yellow', bd=3)
label1.place(x=200, y=20)

label2 = tk.Label(wn, text='', bg='lightgreen', bd=3)
label2.place(x=200, y=50)

update()

wn.mainloop()
```